# R: Passing a dataframe to a function Dynamically

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to dynamically pass some data frames into a function which will return some statistical results for each of the data frames. The aim being to graph the statistical results side by side. I am having problems in that my assignment of the data frame to the function results in the name of the dataframe being passed instead of the actual dataframe itself.

SO for example my dataframe is called `construct 1` but instead of passing the actual dataframe that represents this construct, the code seems to pass the name `construct 1`

Can anyone see how to fix this

```
# Get a list of all the dataframes in the workspace
my.dfs <- names(which(sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))) 

# Filter to just the Alpha DataFrames
my.dfs <- as.data.frame(my.dfs) %>%
  filter(grepl('Alpha_', my.dfs)) %>% 
  mutate(my.table = as.character(my.dfs))

# Loop Through Each Table and get the Alpha Statistics
for (i in 1:nrow(my.dfs)){

  construct = my.dfs$my.table[i]
  construct_name = as.character(my.dfs$my.table[i])

  create_cronbach_summ(construct, construct_name)

}
```

The end result will be something like

```
Construct Name
Statistic 1
Statistic 2
Statistic 3....
```

The error message i recieve is:

```
 Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `deparse(susbtitute(x))` to eval the name and pass the real data.frame for further manipulations. Highly recommended to build a function.
By the way, you should consider using lists, having one data.frame / one outcome per level and extracting information out if `sapply(mylist,FUN=function(element){element$part}`, for example, or `sapply(mylist,FUN=function(element){create_cronback_summ(element)}`.

Comment: Hi @Eric Lecoutre, If i use the following code: `construct = my.dfs$my.table[1]
construct = deparse(substitute(construct))` The variable construct returns "construct". If i look at the variable `my.dfs$my.table[1]` i get the name of the table im looking for in Quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Eric, your solution put me on the right track as i was able to google around and found [this](https://www.quora.com/Could-someone-give-an-explanation-of-how-eval-quote-and-substitute-work-in-R) which led me to this code: `a <- my.dfs$my.table[1]
y = eval(parse(text=a))`